# How to record individual resource performance for a webpage on apache JMeter HTTP Request

Tags: apache, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I am trying to load test a web page using apache Jmeter. I am able to record the response time of the whole web page. Is it possible to see individual performance of each requested resource(all resource request is done via http) of that webpage; so that i can identify which resource is taking time to load.

Comment: I dont understand why this question has been down voted without any reason/comments. I am newbie to testing and JMeter, trying to understand & learn JMeter.

Comment: Please read the [help] pages about what sorts of questions are allowed here on Stack Overflow and on how to write good questions.

Answer (score 0):

See there are two things here

- Web Page performance and
- Actual Server Performance

You can use pagespeed or Yslow to determine how is your individual web page is performing. That will give you total rendering time, size of images, js and css. In case it will suggest if you are missing out on compression or combining js etc.

Next is server performance. It is pretty much possible to measure it but that depends on your requirements. Run your tests for and apply aggregate report. Aggregate report will give you response time for each page. This will be http response and not the rendering time.

I would suggest you come up with realistic workload and then run these tests. Also use some resource monitoring tool like Perfmon, sar or vmstat depending on operating system to monitor the target server performance.